# How to make css a:active work after the click?

Tags: css

I am trying to make a menu working as tabs. The tabs themselves are working fine and the menu links are great aswell.. But I'd like to remove the buttom border of the active tab, to make it look like you're on that actual page. I've tried using `#id a:active` but it seems to work only as long as I press the link. I've had the though about doing it by javascript aswell, but I can't seem to figure out a way to do it. Here's my css for active.

CSS: (please let me know if you'll need more of my css)

```
#navigation a:active {
    color: #000;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#DFE7FA), to(#FFF));
    border-bottom-width:0px;
}
```

Thanks,
/Pyracell

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help. Problem is solved now using a class for my menu id and with links like this: `<a <?php if($_GET['page'] == 'sale') { ?> class='active' <?php } ?> href="index.php?page=sale" ><span> Salg </span></a>`
Again thanks all
/Pyracell

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your demo link in the comments on another answer, JavaScript will not be of any help, it should be done in your PHP code.
Something in the lines of:

```
<a <?php if (this_tab_is_selected){ ?>class='active' <?php } ?>href='LINK_TO_TAB' >
    TAB_NAME
</a>
```

Mentioning that changing tabs is redirecting to another page could have helped with better responses from the start xD

Depending on your code and how you are creating the tabs, you need to change the `this_tab_is_selected` to a code that returns `true` for the selected tab.

P.S. You still need to make the modification mentioned in the other answer in your CSS. (Which is to change `#navigation a:active` to `#navigation a.active`)

Answer (score 8):

Add and remove a class when you select a tab link..

```
#navigation .active {
    color: #000;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#DFE7FA), to(#FFF));
    border-bottom-width:0px;
}
```

and use the script (***jQuery version***)

```
$(function(){

    $('#navigation a').click(function(){

        $('#navigation .active').removeClass('active'); // remove the class from the currently selected
        $(this).addClass('active'); // add the class to the newly clicked link

    });

});
```

Comment: You should mention that in order to use this script, he/she must import the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library.

Comment: @Dan, absolutely right.. the OP mentioned javascript in the question and I interpreted it as jQuery ..

Comment: I've tried to put this into my menu.php (I'm including menu from my index side depending if it's an admin or a user logged in). I put the function into script matching this `<script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js">`. Is that correct or? /Pyracell

Comment: @Pyracell yes, but make sure you close the script tag, and import the jQuery before inserting the script code in the answer.
`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>` `<script type='text/javascript'>/*your JavaScript code goes here*/</script>`

P.S. the language="javascript" tag is deprecated. Use type='text/javascript' instead

Comment: Now my code looks like this (still not working :/ ): `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $('#navigation a').click(function(){

        $('#navigation .active').removeClass('active'); // remove the class from the currently selected
        $(this).addClass('active'); // add the class to the newly clicked link

    });

});
</script>`

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Here you go. The content is in danish due to the organization it's being developed for (and it's still under construction as you might notice) http://theremorseless.dk/kat/index.php

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Do the class overrule `a:hover`, or will it still apply?

Comment: @Pyracell, i see .. I thought the tabs were dynamically loaded. But you are doing a normal navigation with pages being re-loaded.. You will have to add the `active` class from the back-end (PHP). So in your `menu.php` you will need to put a condition on the link that will print `class="active"` to the current one.. does this make sense ?

Comment: @Puracell, yes. Something like that .. but you can just inject the `class` attribute instead of the whole menu (*for maintainability reasons*)

Answer (score 5):

A crude way to do this with JavaScript (jQuery)

```
  $('a[href]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('href') == window.location.pathname || $(this).attr('href') == window.location.href)
      $(this).addClass('active');
  });
```

Comment: This is what we did to spice up the UI of a legacy system, and it worked great. (we did not use "active" to avoid any potential clash with the "active" pseudoclass)

Answer (score 3):

How are you implementing the tabs; as multiple different HTML pages?  The `:active` pseudo-class does indeed only apply when a link is 'active', which generally means 'being clicked on'.  If you're implementing the tabs as multiple HTML pages, you'll probably want to assign a CSS class like "CurrentTab" to the tab representing the page the user is currently on, and apply your `border-bottom-width:0px` to that class.

Answer (score 2):

the practice which is usually followed is to apply a class to your currently selected tab,e.g. class="selected" and then modify your css to target that class

```
#navigation a.selected
```

Comment: Agree strongly with Jags. Not only is this the simplest way but it's also the way to avoid failure to show current page by JavaScript methods if JavaScript has been disabled. Just one more thing:  in each of the .html pages referred to in the navbar, remove the anchor tag around the list item associated with the current page. This stops the server performing unnecessary page refreshes when people idly click on the navbar item for the current page.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how it works. The :active selector matches (as you noticed) a link that is currently getting clicked (= is active/working). What you want, is a selector for the active *page*. You will need to use a normal css class there, like this:

```
#navigation a:active, #navigation a.active {
    color: #000;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#DFE7FA), to(#FFF));
    border-bottom-width:0px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Things like this need to be done with an if statement using code such as PHP.

For example if you click a link you get your new page, set a page variable, something like:

```
$page = "Home";
```

Then use an if statement to add or remove extra CSS classes/ids to chnage the style e.g.

```
if ($page == "home")
{
  <a href="home.php" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="about.php">About</a>
}
else if ($page == "About")
{
  <a href="home.php">Home</a>
  <a href="about.php" class="active">About</a>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late to the party, but I have a simple answer using css only. Give each page a unique id, give each menu item a unique id (or class in this case), style your links as you like for when you are not on the page, then style them as you want them if you are on the page. The css matches when you click on the menu item and it loads the page. So whatever page you are on, the menu item appears "active". Below I have it to where the current page menu button text changes color but you can use the visible property to show and hide images or use any css to style it. (Also in this example is css to change things on hover too.) In addition, this method allows you to write separate css for each menu button, so each menu button can do something different than the others if you wish.

```
#menu {
  padding-top: .5em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Merriweather Sans';
  font-size: 1.25em;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #003300;
 }
#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #003300;
}
#menu a:visited {
  color: #003300;
}
#menu a:hover {
  font-style: italic;
}

#home a.home, 
#about a.about,
#edc a.edc,
#presentations a.presentations,
#store a.store,
#contact a.contact {
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #660000;
}
#home a.home:hover,
#about a.about:hover,
#edc a.edc:hover,
#presentations a.presentations:hover,
#store a.store:hover,
#contact a.contact:hover
{
  font-style: normal;
}
```