# CSS/HTML Active/Hover (Active doesnt work)

Tags: html, css, hover

Heey,

i got a problem, i have to make a webpage for a project, im not an experienced programmer or web-developer and im having a problem with the active CSS.

the purpose is that when i hover my mouse over the sidemenu it would change color, and when it is clicked the color will stay the same as the hover color, the hover part worked when i hover my mouse over the side menu tab (partners) it changes color but when i click it, the color doesnt change it goes away the second i get my mouse off the side menu tab.

Here is my code i hope someone can help me out, i know its a messy code.
CSS:

```
.buttonPartners a:hover{
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right bottom, left top, from(#585858 ), to(#A4A4A4));
}
.buttonPartners a:active { background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right bottom, left top, from(#585858 ), to(#A4A4A4));}
```

HTML:

```
<div class ="buttonPartners"><a href="Partners.html">Partners</a></div>
```

and here the CSS of that class:

```
.buttonPartners  a{
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, from( #B40404 ), to(#FF0000));
Color: white; text-decoration: none; text-align: center; border: 2px solid black; padding: 7px;  position: absolute; font-family: verdana;
top:320px; left:30px; width:105px; height:30px
}
```

hope anyone knows.

Comment: When you change the webpage, the background will still go away. If you really want this you should find a way to know that the user redirected and clicked through that link and change it on that page. Just so you know when you notice that the answers below don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The :active pseudo selector will match when an element is currently being pressed down on by the mouse cursor. It's usually only seen for a split second, and provides visual feedback that the element was indeed clicked.

One choice would be to use a:visited but that will color each link you have pressed.

Or use a bit of jaavscript to add a class to the attribute and then set a color against that class.

Comment: i have tried visited but it stil doesnt work when i click on it and then click on an other page nothing changes it doesnt take the color it supposes to do

Comment: but i got enough comments to work it out further you were right about the active i shall use the other one Thx!

Comment: Check out this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566238/how-to-make-css-aactive-work-after-the-click the jquery example half way down the page showing  $('#navigation a').click(function(){ should be your easiest solution

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
.buttonPartners:hover{
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right bottom, left top, from(#585858 ), to(#A4A4A4));
}
.buttonPartners:active { background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right bottom, left top, from(#585858 ), to(#A4A4A4));}
```

and one question, are you using PHP or only HTML?

Comment: im using HTML for this website

Comment: have you tried the changes? try giving the hover to the div, and not to the "a"

Comment: the answer from @Chris Bertrand is correct, also try seeing this jsFiddle and it might help you  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RG93F/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are wrong with the concept of `:active`

> The :active pseudo-class applies while an element is being activated by the user.

This only work for a few miliseconds doesn't stay after the click event:

> For example, between the times the user presses the mouse button and releases it.

Info from [W3 wikki](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Selectors/pseudo-classes/%3aactive).

Comment: isnt there a way that the TAB stays inlighted? when its on that page?

Comment: With pure JavaScript or Jquery maybe depends on the condition you want

Answer (score 0):

Browsers can view changing the background of a visited link a violation of user privacy as demonstrated here:  [background-image: for :visited links?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202856/background-image-for-visited-links)

A little jquery would do the trick:

```
$('.buttonPartners a').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('colored');
});
```

CSS:

```
.colored { 
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, right bottom, left top, from(#585858 ),     to(#A4A4A4));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4HERF/1/

also, active means while clicked, I think you were looking for :visited, which is the property after a link has been clicked.