# how to Keep the color of active link constant, until i press other link

Tags: html, css

When i click on a link, its color should change, and it should be same until i press other link, How to do using "active"?? I tried, Its color changes when i click on it, But it gains its original color!

```
    <html>
    <head>

    <style>

    a
    {
        display:block;
        height:5%;
        width:10%;
        background-color:#96C;  
        border: solid #96C 1px;
        margin-top:5px;
    }

    a:hover
    {
        background-color:#666;
    }

    a:active
    {
        background-color:#C99;
    }
    </style>


    </head>

    <body>

    <a href="#">Home</a>

    <a href="#">Sign in</a>
    <a href="#">Sign up</a>
    <a href="#">Exit</a>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not what :active pseudo class was meant to do. You can use javascript for this. If you use jQuery, than you can do something like:

```
var items = $("a");
items.on("click",function(){
  items.removeClass("active");
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

and add "active" css rule

```
a.active {
 background-color:#C99;
}
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QQb27/

Answer (score 0):

The `:active` pseudo selector is only active for the brief moment when the link is clicked.

[You can read more here.](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/active/)

In order to get the link to stay the same color you should use a `class` which you can name and implement it on the link for the page you are currently on.

[Here is a link to another thread asking essentially the same question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566238/how-to-make-css-aactive-work-after-the-click)

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript (in my case jQuery) to assign the class to the "active" link. [See this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zEwUY/).

HTML

```
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#">Link 2</a>
```

CSS

```
a { color: green; }
.active { color: orange; }
```

jQuery

```
$('a').on('click', function() {
   $('a').removeClass();
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**Modified version of dward's answer to include your stylings: http://jsfiddle.net/zEwUY/1/**

`a:hover` = Hovering over it.

`a:active` = Holding your mouse down on the link

`a:visited` = What it will look like if you have been there before.