# Keep page active on (non default) nav bar whilst using an 'include nav' function

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I store my navigation in a separate `nav.blade.php` file and use `@include('includes.nav')` to show the navigation in each page. This works great but I lose the ability to highlight the current pages.

This was [resolved here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58146389/how-to-keep-page-active-on-nav-bar-whilst-using-an-include-nav-function/58146412?noredirect=1#comment102678276_58146412) beautifully.

I have a second navigation which **doesn't** use the bootstrap default `active` function, so I thought I'd address this here.

**Page structure**

I have a folder called `user_admin` with it's own bootstrap navigation stored in a file called `nav_user_admin.blade.php`.

This is then called into each page using `@include('includes.nav_user_admin')`.

I include this in the `head`

`@if(Request::is('route-name')) active @endif`

**Nav design**

Each tab has `bg-secondary` with  `text-light`. How would I then show `bg-white` and remove the `text-light` function when page active?

```
<div class="list-group list-group-flush ">
    <a class="nav-link @if(Request::is('home')) active @endif" href="home" id="corner1" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center list-group-item-light list-group-item-action ">Dashboard</a>
    <a class="nav-link @if(Request::is('groups')) active @endif" href="groups" class="bg-secondary text-light list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center list-group-item-light list-group-item-action">Groups I've Created<span class="badge badge-light badge-pill">3</span></a>
    <a class="nav-link @if(Request::is('')) active @endif" href="" class="bg-secondary text-light list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center list-group-item-light list-group-item-action">Groups I've Joined<span class="badge badge-light badge-pill">8</span></a>
    <a class="nav-link @if(Request::is('settings')) active @endif" href="settings" class="bg-secondary text-light list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center list-group-item-light list-group-item-action">Account Settings</a>
    <a class="nav-link @if(Request::is('profile_settings')) active @endif" href="profile_settings" class="bg-secondary text-light list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center list-group-item-light list-group-item-action">Profile Settings</a>
</div>
```

**The problem**

Doing the above gives me a navigation with all tabs bg-secondary and all text blue? There is no difference between active and non active tabs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be done like this

```
<a class="nav-link list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center list-group-item-light list-group-item-action @if(Request::is('settings')) bg-white @else bg-secondary text-light @endif" href="settings">Account Settings</a>
```

Maybe I haven't styled it properly as you want but.

```
@if(Request::is('settings')) the classes you want when it is active @else the classes when it is not active @endif"
```

Comment: Absolutely wonderful. You've saved me days of stress! Thank you.

Comment: glad I could help